# Spring boot ignores configuration classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I created the below:

1. MySpringBootApplication
2. Spring (non-boot) App - ClientApp1
3. Spring (non-boot) App - ClientApp2

ClientApp1 and ClientApp2 are dependencies of MySpringBootApplication

In each, ClientApp1 and ClientApp2  there is MyConfigurationClass.

```
@Configration
public class MyConfigurationClass1{

    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value = "my-prop-1")
    public Properties properties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("prop1", "val");
        return properties;
    }     
}
```

---

```
@Configration
public class MyConfigurationClass2{

    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value = "my-prop-2")
    public Properties properties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("prop2", "val")
        return properties;
    }     
}
```

In ClientApp1 and ClientApp2 I'm using @Autowired with relevant @Qualifier to inject the relevant Properties bean.

While I'm starting MySpringBootApplication its failing on the Below:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Properties' available
```

While putting break points, I can see that only beans from MyConfigurationClass1 being created.

MyConfigurationClass2 is being skipped.

All the 3 apps structure is the same "com.myapp"

What can be the reason that MyConfigurationClass2 is being skipped ?

Thank you.

Comment: if it says "No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Properties' available", wouldn't it imply that MyConfigurationClass1 is not loaded either?

Comment: Thanks, its says "No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Properties' available" for MyClient2 only. I found the issue - I will post it as answer soon. Thank you

Comment: this question doesn't really make sense as-is, and would need considerable clarification. I'm not sure if it is useful to future readers in this form.

Comment: What doesn't make sense to you? for spring developers the questions and the problem should be very clear. If you think more information is needed, let me know and I will update the question. anyway, I will post the answer soon and I think it can be useful for others as well - you can disagree.

Comment: well, how is the problem reproduced? how can the error say something "for MyClient2 only" if they are both dependencies of MySpringBootApplication? In what way is the client configuration different, if one results in error and the other does not? Questions should have [reproducable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but no one can reproduce your problem based on this description.

Comment: And yes, I consider myself Spring developer, as I'm a certified spring professional and I've also contributed to Spring.

Comment: I agree about the error message - I will put the full exception so it will be more clear.